# Closure factory exported from module does not give parent scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, iife

Is it possible for a factory function imported from a module to return a closure that has access to the importing scope? Struggling to understand this in the world of closures and IIFEs. See below

module.js

```
function makeClosure() {
    return function() {
        //I want to access variables from any context where makeClosure is called here
        //I always know variable names here
        //eg:
        console.log(someVar)
    }
}

export default makeClosure
```

anotherModule's.js

```
import makeClosure from './module.js'
let someVar = 'hello!'

let closure = makeClosure()

closure() //print 'hello!'
```

I get a working closure if makeClosure is defined in the module where it is being used, but not if importing from another module. The application in this case is to put a set of functions that operate on the Google Maps API in a module so I can reuse them with different map instances in different parts of my app.

Comment: thats not the way closures work - you'll have to pass those values into `makeClosure`

Comment: No. Closures are based on **lexical scope**, which means the defining environment. It's not dynamic.